# require('devtron').install() causes "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BrowserWindow' of undefined" in electron app

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, electron

I am trying to install the devtron's dev tools from within electron apps developer console and when i try to perform the install i am getting the following error :

```
> require('devtron').install()

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BrowserWindow' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to turn on the `enableRemoteModule` option for the browser window.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 900,
        height: 680,
        webPreferences:{
            nodeIntegration : true,
            enableRemoteModule:true
        }
    });
```